# How do you grab a text field?

Tags: magento-1.9

How do you grab text fields from the Magento ORM back end?

Such as :

($_product->getCaseMeasurement()) ? $_product->getCaseMeasurement() : '';

Which grabs a text field of attribute code "case_measurement" or attribute label "Case Measurement"

If I had a text field of attribute code "clasp" and attribute label "Clasp".

Comment: Do you want the value of the attribute "clasp"?

Comment: Yes, the value of attribute clasp.

Comment: Just use $_product->getClasp();

Comment: I figure it's ($_product->getClasp()) ? $_product->getClasp() : ''
but would like to confirm

Comment: If it is worked for you, I have written as an answer ,please accept so that other can benefited .

Comment: Didn't seem to work for all attributes. Cause an error.

Comment: It should work for all text fields. can you please update your error?

Comment: Fixed a few things, will know in 30 minutes if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grabs a text field of product attribute with code **clasp** and product object is **$_product** use the below code to get value:

```
$clasp_value = $_product->getClasp()!=NULL?$_product->getClasp():'';
```

Comment: It didn't work for label Movement and attribute code movement... I used ($_product->getMovement()) ? $_product->getMovement() : '';
($_product->getMovement()) works the same as != NULL

Worked for everything else

Comment: It worked for all other fields

Comment: I think I found the issue.

Comment: You will not get the attribute label of the the product object. Anyway whats the issue?